# can't get calendar events from Google sheets to Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, workspace

I am trying to set calendar events from schedules I have in Google sheets to google calendar to avoid doing it manually.

[I developed a code and it is giving me error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVSXj.png)

[Here is how my sheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88q3a.png)

```html
function scheduleShifts() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendar_ID = spreadsheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar_ID);

var events = spreadsheet.getRange("H2:I996").getValues();

for (x=0; x<events.length; x++) {

  var schedule = events[x];

  var startTime = schedule[7];
  var endTime = schedule[8];
  var name = schedule[2];
  var address = schedule [3];
  var phone = schedule [4];
  var description = schedule[5];
  var comments = schedule[6];

  eventCal.createEvent(address, startTime, endTime);

  }
  
}

function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Schedule shifts now', 'scheduleShifts')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: From your error message in your provided image, it is considered that the value of `calendar_ID` is an invalid ID. In this case, `eventCal` is `null` instead of occurring as an error. How about confirming the value again? And from your tag of `google-workspace`, how about also confirming that you have permission for accessing the calendar of `calendar_ID` using Google Apps Script? If I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike "In this case, eventCal is null". Would/could this error message be generated if `address`, `startTime`, or `endTime` were null?

Comment: @Tedinoz If my understanding is correct, I think that when the values of `address, startTime, endTime` are invalid, an error like "invalid argument" occurs. I think that the reason for the error like "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createEvent')" is due to that `eventCal` is null.

Comment: Your range has only two columns and your indices show that you are trying to use 9 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cid = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cid);
  var evs = sh.getRange("A2:I996").getValues();
  for (x = 0; x < evs.length; x++) {
    try {
      var ev = evs[x];
      var startTime = new Date(ev[7]);
      var endTime = new Date(ev[8]);
      var address = ev[3];
      cal.createEvent(address, startTime, endTime);
    }
    catch(e){console.error(e); continue;}
  }
}
```

Currently you do not reserve a column to show that the event has been created so that if you run this multiple times you will be creating duplicate events.  You need to think that through.